# RecyclerView pull up loading data response delay in CoordinatorLayout AppBarLayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

My xml layout is shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:id="@+id/root_literature_fm"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

<net.cnki.tCloud.view.widget.TitleBar
    android:id="@id/base_titlebar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/root_literature_fm_literature_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/base_titlebar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap">

            <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
                android:id="@+id/sdv_magazine_cover"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:padding="13dp"
                fresco:actualImageScaleType="centerCrop"
                fresco:placeholderImage="@mipmap/side_surface"
                fresco:placeholderImageScaleType="centerCrop"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_magazine_name"
                style="@style/TextItemMagazineTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sdv_magazine_cover"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:paddingBottom="55dp"
                tools:text="title"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_magazine_date"
                style="@style/TextItemMagazineSubtitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sdv_magazine_cover"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:paddingTop="55dp"
                tools:text="1922"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/layout_literature_filter"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <com.jcodecraeer.xrecyclerview.XRecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/xrv_literature"
        android:name="net.cnki.tCloud.view.fragment.LiteratureFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="false"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<ViewStub
    android:id="@+id/vs_no_literature"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/base_titlebar"
    android:layout="@layout/layout_literature_unbind"/>
```

My problem is delayed response when i slide up the screen to load data. The link is a video of the issue.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VaaAl-omBiY
I think this problem is setting behavior.This touch event is a delay passed to RecyclerView.
Please help me this problem has been bothering me for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

this is a bug of supportlibrary,and not fixed in 27.1.0
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/66996774
try https://gist.github.com/chrisbanes/8391b5adb9ee42180893300850ed02f2, it works